# Is there a way to enable 'Clear All Notification' button while config_showRecentAndOldHeaders is set to true

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-source, android-automotive

I'm working on Automotive AOSP Android 12.

I'm trying to enable the button "Clear All Notification" by overlaying the SystemUI config but it seems impossible while "config_showRecentAndOldHeaders = true".
Based on what I found under Notification module (android/packages/apps/Car/Notification/src/com/android/car/notification/template/CarNotificationFooterViewHolder.java), if "config_showRecentAndOldHeaders = true", the "mClearAllButton" is transformed to "ManageButton".

```
if (mShowRecentsAndOlderHeaders) {
                mClearAllButton.setText(R.string.manage_text);
                if (!mClearAllButton.hasOnClickListeners()) {
                    mClearAllButton.setOnClickListener(this::manageButtonOnClickListener);
                }
            } else {
                if (!mClearAllButton.hasOnClickListeners()) {
                    mClearAllButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                        mNotificationItemController.clearAllNotifications();
                    });
                }
            }
```

Thank you.